# How can I access the low level psycopg2 connection in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to access the low level psycopg2 connection object to use the psycopg2.extensions.lobject class in my django project.

```
from django.db import connection
```

does not provide what I need. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see [from the source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/db/__init__.py#L78) that `from django.db import connection` returns a `DatabaseWrapper` for the default DB. [In the psycopg2 backend](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py#L140) you'll see that the `DatabaseWrapper` accesses the low level connection via `connection.cursor().connection`.

Comment: It is even easier. connection.connection returns what I need.

Comment: @OliverAndrich `connection.connection` doesn't work for me in management commands. `django.db.connection` is a `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper` there, which has a `connection` of `None`. (Tested in Django 1.8a1.) `connection.cursor().connection` seems cumbersome but works reliably for me.

Answer (score 2):

Those answers are good but not copypastable and with outdated docs so let me fix that.
As of [version 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) you use the raw connection like that

```
from django.db import connection

stmt = "SELECT * FROM foo"

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: In your example, the `connection` object is a Django `DefaultConnectionProxy` instance. The question is about getting access the underlying psycopg2 connection object, which you can do using `connection.cursor().connection`.

Comment: Or `connection.connection`, but see the caveat in Heinrik Heimbueger's comment under [Mark Lavin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405315/456550) above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django 1.2+, you should probably change that to:

```
from django.db import connections['default']
```

or something equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. And I will do so. But sadly, this is still not the connection I need. It is essentially a wrapper around my psycopg2 connection.